# swiftUI binding function value

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have this code that creates an image:

```swift
func getImage() -> Image {
   if coupons[index].image.isEmpty {
        return Image(systemName: "tag")
   }
   else {
        return Image(uiImage: UIImage(data: coupons[index].image) ?? UIImage())
   }
}
var body: some View {
   getImage()
}
```

`coupons[index].image` is updated on the same page in another section. I want `getImage()` to update when `coupons[index].image` is changed, because `Binding` doesn't work.

Edit:
`coupons` is a `State` variable which is taken from UserDefaults. `index` is a `State` variable. `coupons[index].image` is updated  using an `ImagePicker`.

Comment: We need minimal reproducible example of your problem

Comment: If `coupons` and `index` are both `@State` variables, from what I can see, this should work fine. We need more information and code

Comment: @CloudBalancing I'm not sure that's too relevant here, but we still need more info in the question to know how to help

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible approach base on your given code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        getImage(data: coupons[index].image)
    }
    
    func getImage(data: Data?) -> Image {
        
        let failureImage: Image = Image(systemName: "tag")
        
        if let safeData: Data = data {
            
            if let unwrappedUIImage: UIImage = UIImage(data: safeData) { return Image(uiImage: unwrappedUIImage) }
            else { return failureImage }
  
        }
        else { return failureImage }
        
    }
    
}
```